# How to send values by key=>value as post method swift

Tags: java, android

I would like to send some parameters by `key=>value` like `volley` library in android (like a `form` html).

I dont't want to send values as json parameters.

how can I do ?

in volley library :

```
 Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
        // the POST parameters:
        params.put("site", "code");
        params.put("network", "tutsplus");
```

Comment: Please show your tried code

Comment: I'm an android developer and I don't know how can I send a value like parameters without json value.  in volley  `  Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
        // the POST parameters:
        params.put("site", "code");
        params.put("network", "tutsplus"); `

Comment: you can use AFNetworking, Alamofire or NSUrlsession for it

Comment: better try retrofit @S.M_Emamian

Comment: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:) doesn't convert them to json params. It converts the Dictionary to Data. Dictionary is some how related to json structure that why JSONSerialization can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Dictionary` and the serialise the dictionary as JSON and set it as `HTTPBody`:

```
let parameters = ["site":"code", "network":"tutsplus"] as Dictionary<String, String>
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:YOURURL)!)
let session = URLSession.shared
request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
```

The alternative would be:

```
request.httpBody = "site=code&network=tutsplus"
```

Comment: The post body as the hall request at the end its just text.

Comment: When you use the serialisable and the dict you dont worry about text escaping. to include spaces and backslashes etc.

Comment: As I remember the dictionary is based on json structure. You can see that when you print the dictionary on the console

Comment: you can serialize it in query params without thinking about escaping using `parameters.map({ key, value in URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value) })` and then putting in `URLComponents` resulting array. Also, can you edit `request` initialization line? It doesn't even compile. And for `Swift 3` it would be better to use swift struct `URLRequest`.

Comment: @user28434 It is a post request. params go in body. The point is the escaping should be done in both cases. either in query string or in body.

Comment: `URLQueryItem` takes care of escaping, and `URLRequest` takes care about putting query params in proper place. Also `request` should be `var`, it's a `struct` and you're mutating it. Is there any `Swift` compiler/playground near you to check code validity?

Answer (score -1):

You can just set the keys and values in the httpBody, as such:

```
request.httpBody = "key=value"
```

You kan even add more keys by adding '&', kind of like you would usually do in a GET

```
request.httpBody = "key=value&otherKey=otherValue"
```